# Requiring unknown module, can't import a custom component from index.android.js

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react native so this must be easy:

My (simple) application:

index.android.js

```
import SearchContainer from './components/SearchContainer.jsx';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyFirstApp', () => SearchContainer);
```

and in components/SearchContainer.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class SearchContainer extends Component {
  ....
}
```

but I'm getting

```
 Requiring unknown module "./components/SearchContainer.jsx".If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager or running "npm install".
```

I've tried a moving the SearchContainer to the same directory as index.android.js and I get the same thing.

Thanks a bunch in advance, friends!

Comment: try `import SearchContainer from './components/SearchContainer'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out a way this will work, but I'm not sure what the science behind it is - I guess "jsx" is a take over from React that simply doesn't belong.

I simply changed "jsx"  to "js" and it worked.

Comment: You should remove the extension altogether, except if you're importing `json`, or non-JS files.

Comment: not adding the extension works, but of course only after I changed the actual file extension to js